# Check enum valueOf in Java Optional mapping pipeline

Tags: java, spring, enums, stream, java-stream

I have the following method and at here I first get name of `exportProductType` and then get the value of that name. If `name` or the `valueOf(name)` is null, then throw exception.

```
public static ProductType getExportProductType(ExportProductType exportProductType) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(exportProductType)
            .map(ExportProductType::name)
            .map(ProductType::valueOf)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ProductTypeNotFoundException());
}
```

Everything is ok and works without any problem. However, when I pass `exportProductType` enum value that is not available in `ProductType` enums, I cannot catch it and it throws another exception "No enum constant...". So, I think I need to check if `ProductType::valueOf` is null before `.map(ProductType::valueOf)`. How should I check it? Using a boolean or filter? Or another way that is proper for `stream()` in Java?

I think something like that after `.map(ExportProductType::name)`:

`.filter(result -> ProductType::valueOf(result) != null)`

**Update:** I found a proper way as shown below:

`EnumUtils.isValidEnum(ProductType.class, exportProductType.name());`

I just need to use it in `stream()`. So, is it possible to make the same check in a `stream()`? Is this ok just below the `.map(ExportProductType::name)` line?

`.filter(x -> EnumUtils.isValidEnum(ProductType.class, x))`

Comment: You need to either catch the exception from `valueOf` or check beforehand that the value is actually in the enum.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes, I know. But how?

Comment: I’m not sure what more information you need - use a `try…catch` block to catch and handle the exception. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, but `filter(x -> EnumUtils.isValidEnum(ProductType.class, x))` seems to working. Just wanted to ask if it is a good approach or not.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the `IllegalArgumentException` by `valueOf` would have to be handled, so for example, you can instead define your own value lookup method that would return an empty Optional instead of throwing an exception:

```
enum ProductType {
    ...
    
    static Optional<ProductType> nullableValueOf(String name) {
        try {
            return Optional.of(ProductType.valueOf(name));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
   }
}

public static ProductType getExportProductType(ExportProductType exportProductType) throws ProductTypeNotFoundException {
    return Optional.ofNullable(exportProductType)
                   .map(ExportProductType::name)
                   .flatMap(ProductType::nullableValueOf)
                   .orElseThrow(() -> new ProductTypeNotFoundException());
}
```

**EDIT:**

While you're at using `Optional` already, it would be cleaner to also use it as the return type:

```
public static Optional<ProductType> getExportProductType(ExportProductType exportProductType) throws ProductTypeNotFoundException {
    return Optional.ofNullable(exportProductType)
                   .map(ExportProductType::name)
                   .flatMap(ProductType::nullableValueOf);
}
```

Comment: return optional instead of explicitly throwing exception, please.

Comment: @MA Thanks for reply, but can I solve the problem just making an update on my method instead of enums?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thank you! The `flatMap` is indeed convenient in this case.

Comment: @Henry the enum does not have to be changed, you can define the helper method in some other class.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But why is there any method to check a condition in `stream()`. I do not want to create a helper method or update enums. Just need to make operation in the stream part. Any idea?

Comment: @Henry In fact there are no streams in this code, you're only working with `Optional`. Methods that act like conditions exist like `ifPresent`, but the problem here is the `valueOf` method from enum throws an unchecked exception, there is no condition involved. This exception indicates that an `ExportProductType` bears a name that is not valid, in other words, something is bad about the product.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my **Update**?

Answer (score 0):

Libraries like [Vavr](https://www.vavr.io/) implement functional helpers like:

```
static <A, T> Function<A, Optional<T>> Try(Function<A, T> f) {
    return a -> {
        try {
            return Optional.of(f.apply(a));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    };
}
```

wrapping the exception into a pure functional type. With this, you can map, filter, etc... invalid states:

```
enum EnumX { Foo, Bar }

Stream
        .of("Foo", "Bar", "Par")
        .map(Try(EnumX::valueOf))
        .forEach(System.out::println);

Stream
        .of("Foo", "Bar", "Par")
        .map(Try(EnumX::valueOf))
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

with output

```
Optional[Foo]
Optional[Bar]
Optional.empty
Foo
Bar
```

NOTE: [full running example code here](https://onlinegdb.com/9o58_VNCg)

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class EnumStreamCheck {

    static <A, T> Function<A, Optional<T>> Try(Function<A, T> f) {
        return a -> {
            try {
                return Optional.of(f.apply(a));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return Optional.empty();
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {

        Stream
                .of("Foo", "Bar", "Par")
                .map(Try(EnumX::valueOf))
                .forEach(System.out::println);

        Stream
                .of("Foo", "Bar", "Par")
                .map(Try(EnumX::valueOf))
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    enum EnumX {
        Foo, Bar
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working, what is `.map(Try(EnumX::valueOf))`? `Try` is not recognized

Comment: It's the function I'd defined there :) (to not require additional libraries)

Comment: Why do not use the code that I posted? Your code seems to be messy and not useful :(

Comment: ANd still not worrking with not available references e.g. `Try`

Comment: @Henry probably you miss the `package ...`.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my **Update**?